# How to get the angle between the bisector (with 3 points given) and the abscisse.

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I have three random points in a 2D space, $A$, $B$ and $C$, how can I compute the angle between the abscisse and the bisector of $ABC$:

[image]

So I am looking for the angle $α$ (in red).

I'm using a computer and I can easily compute the azimuth $AZIMUTH_{BA}$ and $AZIMUTH_{BC}$

[image]

For this specific example I can do:

$$\frac{AZIMUTH_{BA}-AZIMUTH_{BA}}{2} + \frac{5\pi}{2} - AZIMUTH_{BA}$$

To get the angle $α$.

But how can I get a generalized formula to always get the right $α$ angle between $0$ and $2\pi$ ?

Comment: Well, if you have the coordinates of of all the points, you could calculate the vector
$$
\vec{v}_{\text{bisector}} = \frac{\vec{BA} + \vec{BC}}{2}
$$
And then you could just use dot product to calculate the angle $\alpha$.

Comment: The dot product between $v_{bisector}$ and the abscisse ?

Comment: Yeah, you could take $\vec{v}_{\text{bisector}} \cdot (- \hat{i})$.

Comment: @MattiP. That only produces the bisector when $\lvert\overrightarrow{BA}\rvert=\lvert\overrightarrow{BC}\rvert$. If the vectors are of different lengths, you need to normalize them first. Try, for example, $A=(10,0)$, $B=(0,0)$ and $C=(0,1)$.